# Operand should contain 1 column(s) while insert in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are user and info. Need to insert into info table with max id from user table.I tried using below query with single row insert it was working fine. But I try to multiple insert it doesn't. getting error as "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

```
INSERT INTO user( name, email, password )
values
    (
        ((SELECT MAX( id ) as id from info), 'test1@gmail.com', '123'),
        ((SELECT MAX( id ) as id from info), 'test1@gmail.com', '123'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting from a select, we don't need to use `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO user( name, email, password )
SELECT MAX(id), 'test1@gmail.com', '123' FROM info
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id), 'test1@gmail.com', '123' FROM info;
```

Note also that you probably don't need to wrap the `MAX(id)` query as a subquery.  Instead, just select the constants you want in a single top level query.